# JqGrid, DatePicker no value in the toolbar when selecting

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, datepicker, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm trying to add a Datepicker filter on a JQGrid toolbar. When I click on the date filter, no problem the Datepicker shows up, but when I select my date, nothing happen. The date I've chose doesn't appear in the toolbar filter and of curse no search  is launch.
Did I miss something?
Here is my code:

```
colModel: [                     
    { name: 'Period', index: 'Period', align: 'left', formatter: 'date',
        search: true,
        searchoptions: {
        dataInit: function (el) {
            $(el).datepicker({
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                    $("#grid_id")[0].triggerToolbar();
                }
            });
        }
    }}
]
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the searching toolbar is that the code from `onSelect` callback could be executed too early. So you should start the code in another thread and allow the current work be done till the end:

```
colModel: [                     
    { name: 'Period', index: 'Period', align: 'left', formatter: 'date',
        search: true,
        searchoptions: {
        dataInit: function (el) {
            $(el).datepicker({
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                onSelect: function () {
                    if (this.id.substr(0, 3) === "gs_") {
                        // call triggerToolbar only in case of searching toolbar
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $("#grid_id")[0].triggerToolbar();
                        }, 100);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }}
]
```

The test for `id` of the current `<input>` field I inserted to be sure that we don't try to use `triggerToolbar` in searching dialog. I mean that one can combine searching toolbar for simple searching with [advanced searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching) for more complex searching requests.